# Do road bike shoes offer an increase in power transfer over mtb shoes if the sole is a similar stiffness?

Tags: pedals

Is there an argument against the use of road shoes if your were planning on time trialling and criterium races?

Comment: Why would you time trial with a heavier shoe even if it had the same stiffness?  Why would you time trial with mtb pedals?  Are you going to time trial on mtb bike?

Comment: MTB pedals and shoes have their place on MTB!

Comment: @Carel It is possible to do occasional professional road racing with MTB pedals and shoes https://cyclingtips.com/2017/05/cyclocrosser-katerina-nash-takes-womens-tour-california-stage-3-report/ For an amateur - why not? If (s)he is used to those shoes and they work well?

Comment: @VladimirF It's a matter of principle! ;-) Road shoes and pedals for road bikes and MTB on MTB. Each thing has its place. You don't dance the tango with crocs or flip-flops.

Answer (score 3):

It’s probably more a matter of pedal systems than shoes. High end shoes in both categories will be pretty good and stiff.

I can only talk about Speedplay Zero (road bike pedals) vs. Look Quartz and Shimano SPD. The Speedplay Zero have a much greater area, have completly free adjustable movement sideways (as far as the crankarms allow it) and no play, tilting etc. whatsoever. Other road bike systems will probably be similarly good.

Road bike shoes will probably be lighter and have more openings for air to come in.

The only disadvantage of road bike shoes is that it’s really almost impossible to walk in them and the cleats suffer much more wear from it.